# Python List ordering

Tags: python, list

I have a list `a = [2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0].`

I want the output to be `order = [5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 8]`.

The output should be a list of **index+1** of the elements arranged in non-increasing order of a and wherever there is same value of **a** it should be arranged in increasing order of index. Here index of max element is 4 so 5 comes first and then there are indexes 0, 1, 5. So 1, 2, 6 comes.

Is there any short pythonic way to achieve this without using loops?

I have tried this with **reverse = True**

```
order = [i+1 for (v,i) in sorted(((v, i) for (i, v) in enumerate(a)),reverse=True)].
```

But this does not keep the indexes as desired wherever there is same value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this does not keep the indexes as desired wherever there is same value.

It does, but you are sorting in *reverse*! So the indices for `1` - `1`, `2` and `6` - are coming ordered `6`, `2`, `1`. Flip the index to sort correctly:

```
[-i+1 for (v,i) in sorted(((v, -i) for (i, v) in enumerate(a)),reverse=True)]
# => [5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 7, 8, 4, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you don't want zeros indices in your result.

The `key` parameter of `sorted()` is what you're looking for.

Try this :

```
a = [2, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
order = [ i + 1 for (i, n) in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True) if n > 0 ]
```

See the [`sorted()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) for more details.